# Can a Pakistani with valid Saudi Resident Card travel to Georgia?

Tags: pakistani-citizens, georgia-country, tbilisi

I am holding a valid resident ID card of the Kingdom of Saudi Arabia and I am a Pakistani national. Can I travel to Georgia with visa free entry?

Comment: Why do you think you can travel visa free to any country ? Best idea is to check the country's consulate for information on visas. http://www.advantour.com/georgia/visa/visa-free-360.htm Here it shows yu cannot avail of the visa free entry.

Comment: Why can they not think so? Just because of their natiOnality? There are millions of people who are born with the idea of visa free entry to many countries so OP thinking so In all innocence is nothing special to question. Even if the answer is no there is nothing wrong With OP asking whether it is possible

Comment: Having Saudi *residence* does not give you Saudi *citizenship*. The rules that govern visas are primarily driven by your citizenship, and only in rare cases affected by additional residencies.